# Image and shortcode not showing in excerpt

Tags: images, shortcode

I've paid to someone to create a theme for me. Everything works fine, except the excerpt on category posts.

It only shows an excerpt of the post ( not image ) and when I add a shortcode in the excerpt, it show this as text and doesn't compile it

When I go to full post, the image and shortcodes works well.

I can add the image on top of the post by using image post type and set feature image, but it will be ugly in full post and still problem with shortcodes in shortpost

What can I do? My designer is out of touch and does not answer me after receiving his money.

Answer (score 1):

To get shortcodes to work in the excerpt you'll have to add a filter to your **functions.php** file (found inside your theme folder).

```
add_filter('the_excerpt', 'do_shortcode');
```

Your other question about the images not showing is hard to answer without knowing how your theme code is like. It has to do with how your designer build the category pages.

If you want to show the full posts instead of just the excerpt, find the file responsible to render the category loop (probably: category.php), and in that file where it says `the_excerpt();`replace that with `the_content();`

Comment: Thanks so much , replace that with the_content(); works for show image in shortpost !!

but still my video shortcodes not work even when i add add_filter('the_excerpt', 'do_shortcode'); to function.php

Answer (score 0):

Please use

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( $content ) ?>
```

instead of "plain" shortcode. It's very hard to tell you what you shut do because the problem you have written about is very simple specified. Beacuse i can't comment I will try help you by replying for this answer if problem will occured again

**UPDATE**

```
add_filter('the_excerpt', 'do_shortcode');
```

to the end of functions.php file in your  theme directory

Works for me

Best regards

Comment: thanks for reply my friend , i put add_filter('the_excerpt', 'do_shortcode'); in my function.php but nothing change still shortcode not compile in shortpost

what you mean about : <?php echo do_shortcode( $content ) ?>

for example if my shortcode is [video] where i must put it ??